# animate an image like cardiogram

Tags: iphone, animation

i have an image [image]

i want to animate this image continuously i.e entering from left end of screen and exit at right end for this i'm using this code..

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:15];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:NO];
cardioImage1.frame = CGRectMake(330, 0, 320, 100);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This code animate images only for one time.

I want to make it continuous animation for  certain time frame. 
What can i do for that... please  help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set some value to this property : 
`setAnimationRepeatCount`

Perhaps use `FLT_MAX` for infinite loop

Comment: This image repeat after ones the animation is complete.at intermediate  time screen is blank. is it possible to never left screen blank.always image animate.    i.e portion that exit from right end same portion enter from left end.

Comment: Try this link : http://blog.stormyprods.com/2009/10/simple-scrolling-uilabel-for-iphone.html